# Word template with rich text fields restricted to filling in fields only

Tags: 2010, document-template

I have a SharePoint list with several rich text columns. I have made a Word template for the list, with the columns added to the template as document properties. I would like to restrict editing of the document to filling in fields only, but enabling that setting disables rich text editing of the rich text fields.

Not restricting editing allows for the user to delete fields and otherwise reformat the document, which I want to prevent. How can I best accomplish this goal?